# Is this a valid proof that $\forall_{x,y}\left[x\ne y\implies x<y\lor x>y\right]$ in $\mathbb{N}_1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction, peano-axioms

I do not consider the following to prove all of the so-called *trichotomy of order*, since I take that to be a statement that exactly one of $<.=,>$ holds for any given pair of numbers.

The notation $x^\prime$ indicates the successor of $x$, as in Peano's axioms. The expression $a<b$ is defined to be $a<b\iff\exists_c a+c=b.$

The objective is to show that, for the natural numbers beginning with
1 we have

$$
\forall_{x,y}\left[x\ne y\implies x<y\lor x>y\right].
$$

It is easily shown that every number is either 1 or a successor. Furthermore,
$\forall_{x}x^{\prime}>1$. We shall also accept $x^\prime +y=x +y^\prime$.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of numbers
$x$ such that, for all numbers $y$ the implication $x\ne y\implies x<y\lor x>y$ 
holds. That is

$$
\mathcal{M}\equiv\left\{ x\backepsilon\forall_{y}\left[x\ne y\implies x<y\lor x>y\right]\right\} .
$$

The principle of induction requires us to show that $1\in\mathcal{M}$
and that for all $x\in\mathcal{M}$ it follows that $x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}.$
For the case of $x=1$ we have

$$
x=1\implies x=y=1\lor\exists_{z}y=z^{\prime}>1=x.
$$

Since $1\ne y=z^{\prime}$ we have $1\in\mathcal{M}.$

Now we assume $x\in\mathcal{M},$ which means we need to consider
the following three cases:

In the **first case** we have $y$ such that $x<y.$ So

$$
x<y\iff\exists_{c}\left[y=x+c\land\left(c>1\lor c=1\right)\right].
$$

This has **two sub-cases**. In the **first sub-case**

$$
1<c\land x<y=x+c
$$

$$
\iff\exists_{d}\left[y=x+c=x+d^{\prime}\iff y=x^{\prime}+d\right]
$$

$$
\iff x^{\prime}<y.
$$

In the **second sub-case**

$$
1=c\land x<y=x+c=x^{\prime}.
$$

The **second case** is $y$ such that $x=y.$ So $x^{\prime}=y+1>y.$

The **third case** is $y$ such that $x>y.$ So we have

$$
x=y+c\implies x^{\prime}=y+c^{\prime}>y.
$$

The induction hypothesis assumes that every $y$ is in one of these
cases, so $x^{\prime}\ne y\implies x^{\prime}<y\lor y<x^{\prime}.$

We thereby conclude $x\in\mathcal{M}\implies x^{\prime}\in\mathcal{M}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have two up-votes, and no disagreement, I sense that others approve of my proof.  It makes sense to me, so I am accepting it as valid.

It is motivated by [Thurston](https://archive.org/details/TheNumberSystem)'s method of proof, and, IMO, is more elegant and satisfying than the proof outlined in BBFSK; discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168874/342834).